# How to save response data of a http sampler in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I've a testplan with one http sampler in thread group. I want to run the test for  5 minutes. How can I store the results of sampler with request and response data into a file showing same like as in view results tree listener?

Answer (score 5):

1. Add the next lines to *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder):

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the properties up
3. [Run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
4. Once your test is finished open JMeter GUI, add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, locate `result.jtl` file using "Browse" button - you should see requests and responses details.

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

---

Remember that storing request and especially response data causes **massive Disk IO overhead** so don't forget to remove the aforementioned lines once you won't be needing verbose information anymore.